# Identifying article tags

Tags: html, regex, parsing, html-parsing, pattern-matching

I'm trying to identify tags of a given URL.

Is there any convention for tag specification? Any heuristic that is based on common usages?

I'm referring to in-site tags that categorize it's content. e.g. in each TC article you can find in the end a 'tags' section. Same goes for most content sites.

Comment: There is no real convention, no.... this may be harder than it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question. I believe you are referring to tags like 'html' 'regex' and so on like at the end of your question.

In theory, you could assume, that pages use the `rel="xyz"` for tag links.
Stackoverflow does it, and a few other sites I know do it too.

http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-tag

But I don't think its very reliable. As there is no 'must' and such tags are not guaranteed.

Anyhow, if you want to try it and parse the content, I would not suggest doing it from scratch. [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for example provides a lot of functionality in a very slick library. You can even find link tags which have specific attributes with it.